# Converting a build using callback hell to promise hell

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I am currently in the process of converting a build process with some callback hell into promise hell (hell most likely due to me being new to promises and my inexperience with Bluebird). I am struggling to get past the `.all` method with errors that a file already exists. Perhaps the file copies within it are attempting to happen before `rimraf` at the start?

```
const Promise    = require('bluebird');
const rcopyAsync = Promise.promisify(require('recursive-copy'));
const readAsync  = Promise.promisify(require('recursive-readdir'));
const rmrfAsync  = Promise.promisify(require('rimraf'));
const globAsync  = Promise.promisify(require('glob'));

rmrfAsync('{build,dist}')
    .then(() => {
        return readAsync('src');
    })
    .then((files) => {
        if (!files.length) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('No source to compile.'));
        }

        return Promise.resolve(true);
    })
    .all([
        rcopyAsync(`${__dirname}/scripting`, 'build'),
        rcopyAsync(`${__dirname}/compiler/${process.platform}`, 'build'),
        rcopyAsync('src/scripting', 'build')
    ])
    .then(() => {
        return globAsync('*.sma', { cwd: 'build' });
    })
    .then((files) => {
        console.log(files);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        throw err;
    });
```

For anyone interested, the working portion of the callback hell is below:

```
...

rmrf('{build,dist}', err => {
    if (err) throw err;

    read('src', (err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!files.length) return;

        rcopy(`${__dirname}/scripting`, 'build', err => {
            if (err) throw err;

            rcopy(`${__dirname}/compiler/${process.platform}`, 'build', err => {
                if (err) throw err;

                rcopy('src/scripting', 'build', err => {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    glob('*.sma', { cwd: 'build' }, (err, files) => {
                        if (err) throw err;

                        console.log(files);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being tricked by how promises work. When you first execute your javascript, all of the parts of the chain are built. Because, in building your chain, you call `rcopyAsync`, `rcopyAsync` will start immediately. If you want something to occur later, you need to wrap it in a `.then`.

```
rmrfAsync('{build,dist}')
.then(() => {
    return readAsync('src');
})
.then((files) => {
    if (!files.length) {
        /* Could even be:
        throw new Error('No source to compile');
        */
        return Promise.reject(new Error('No source to compile.'));
    }
})
.then(() => {
    // Wait until the previous promise finished before starting the rcopyAsync
    return Promise.all([
        rcopyAsync(`${__dirname}/scripting`, 'build'),
        rcopyAsync(`${__dirname}/compiler/${process.platform}`, 'build'),
        rcopyAsync('src/scripting', 'build')
    ]);
})
...
```

You want to defer your execution. If you do something outside of a function wrapper, then it will be executed immediately. If you put it inside the function wrapper, it will only be executed once the previous call finishes.

Comment: The `return Promise.resolve(true);` does not appear to be needed.

Comment: I originally just c&p the source. I cleaned it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

ES2017 have the `async/await` syntax

> To prevent `Promise hell`

So, your code should be

```
async function foo() {
    await rmrfAsync('{build,dist}')

    var files = await readAsync('src')  
    if (!files.length)
        throw new Error('No source to compile.');

    await Promise.all([
        rcopyAsync(`${__dirname}/scripting`, 'build'),
        rcopyAsync(`${__dirname}/compiler/${process.platform}`, 'build'),
        rcopyAsync('src/scripting', 'build')
    ])
    var files =  await globAsync('*.sma', { cwd: 'build' })
    console.log(files)
    return files
}

foo()
.then(files => something(files))
.catch(e => console.log('throw errors or rejecteds'))
```